# How does oat malt work for steeping?

Tags: extract, extract-plus-grains, oats

I'm presently an extract, partial boil brewer.  I was thinking of steeping oat malt (from, for example, [Thomas Fawcett](http://www.fawcett-maltsters.co.uk/range.htm)).  Will this work?  I'm using a recipe [here](http://crampedspacebrew.blogspot.com/2010/12/blue-moon-clone.html), which calls for flaked oats.  But [oats must be mashed with barley malt to utilise them](http://www.howtobrew.com/section2/chapter12-2.html).

So is steeping oat malt a waste of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue will be if oat malt has enough diastatic power to convert itself.  If so, you can do a minimash (really just a steep with controlled water amount, temp, and time).  If not, you'll need to add some pale malt and do the same process.  But oat malt will not give you the same flavor results as flaked oats.  For the 4 oz. that's called for in the recipe, it may not make much difference which method you use, or even if you leave them out.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking I'd just leave it out and see what the head retention and mouth feel was like.  Thanks.